# accordion slider on different style of unorderred list

Tags: jquery, accordion

here is my html

```
<div id="1" class="category_group">
<ul class="top_level_category">
    <li><a>top level title 1</a>
        <ul class="sub_level_category">
            <li>lower level links</li>
            <li>lower level links</li>
            <li>lower level links</li>
            <li>lower level links</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

```
<div id="2" class="category_group">
<ul class="top_level_category">
    <li><a>top level title 2</a>
        <ul class="sub_level_category">
            <li>lower level links</li>
            <li>lower level links</li>
            <li>lower level links</li>
            <li>lower level links</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

and this will be my jquery

```
$('div ul li ul').hide();
$('div ul li a').click(function() {
$(this).find('ul').show();
});
```

I am making an accordion but cant do it, the list structure is different from the normal ones

[sample](http://jsfiddle.net/zU6wD/)

Answer (score 1):

`find()` searches for a specified descendant element(s) of the selected element,  you can use `next` method:

```
$('div ul li a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).next('ul').toggle();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6rXp2/

Answer (score 0):

Change `$(this).find('ul').show();` with `$(this).parent().find('ul').show();` or `$(this).next('ul').show();`